# Does every irrational number contain "$666$" in its decimal expansion?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Say $x$ is satanic if $x$ contains "$666$" somewhere in its decimal expansions. Let $S$ be the set of such numbers. Is
> $$
> \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \subseteq S 
> $$
> More generally, for any finite string of digits, say $y = y_1y_2y_3\ldots y_{n-1}y_n$, does $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ necessarily contain $y$ in its decimal expansion.

It seems intuitive that, at least, for any $y$, $y$ should be contained in $\textit{almost every }$ irrational number, since the irrational numbers have an infinite decimal expansion. But, I could envision there exists some irrational number that follows some pattern such that it doesn't contain some $y$.

Comment: For an example that came up in a recent Question, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330853/is-the-sum-of-infinite-recurring-decimals-also-a-recurring-decimal).  It is pretty well known that a decimal expansion which neither terminates nor (eventually) repeats periodically is thus representative of an irrational number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There are even [transcendental numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) all of whose digits are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all numbers are satanic, in the sense that the **Lebesgue measure** of the numbers that do not contain 666, or any other particular finite sequence, is zero.

Also in terms of **Baire category** almost all numbers are satanic, since any finite sequence can be extended to be satanic.

On the other hand, in terms of **cardinality** there are as many non-satanic numbers as satanic numbers, because there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ of each: just consider numbers whose decimal expansion contains nothing but 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 2):

For a concrete example, take
$$x=0.101001000100001000001\ldots1\underbrace{00\dots0}_{n\text{ zeros}}1\underbrace{00\dots0}_{n+1\text{ zeros}}1\dots.$$
This decimal expansion isn't periodic (since it contains arbitrarily long runs of zeros), and so $x$ is irrational. You can do something similar to avoid any string of digits you want, not just $666$.